# How to best cache server responses on server side with Jetty and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, caching, jetty

I'm using embedded Jetty 6 and Spring Web. What is the best way to cache served pages in this setup to avoid regenerating them on every request?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to cache exactly? If you're trying to reduce file I/O from constantly reading template content from disk, [StringTemplateGroup](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/index.html?org/antlr/stringtemplate/StringTemplateGroup.html) automatically does this.

You can configure the caching settings (how frequently the cache is invalidated) by using [StringTemplateGroup#setRefreshInteval(int)](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/org/antlr/stringtemplate/StringTemplateGroup.html#setRefreshInterval(int)).

Comment: I'm trying to cache the entire response, on per-request basis. I guess I'd better delete reference to ST from my question.

Answer (score 0):

Spring 3.1 supports a [Cache Abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/cache.html) that can be used to cache web responses.